# How to create a 4 node cluster in Google cloud to run an HPC application

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, cluster-computing

I think i read every document Google cloud has but not finding an answer. Everything seems to be targeted for web services.

I want to create a cluster of 4 identical nodes in google cloud engine and run an MPI pingpong or an MPI application. I'm very new to cloud computing

Ideally if i can use a "gold" instance that i can set up with the tools i need and use it to create the cluster.

Any help is appreciated it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of compute options on Google Cloud. It sounds like you might be looking at App Engine, which is Google's platform-as-a-service offering. As you indicated, it is definitely geared towards creating web applications. Instead you should consider either Compute Engine or Kubernetes Engine (also known as Container Engine). Compute Engine allows you to create virtual machines, which will absolutely let you install whatever software you choose. You can select from a number of different operating systems for your virtual machine, including Debian, CentOS, Ubuntu, Red Hat, SUSE and Windows. You can create your first virtual machine, install your software and configure the virtual machine the way you'd like, take a snapshot of it, and then generate additional virtual machines from the snapshot.

If your environment lends itself to being run in a container, you might want to consider Kubernetes Engine. Kubernetes Engine allows you to create Docker-style containers, which are more lightweight and boot faster than traditional VM's. If you want your application to be able to launch additional nodes and scale up rapidly, Kubernetes Engine would definitely be worth investigating.

Google's Cloud website (https://cloud.google.com) has a ton of information on both of these options. If you'd like more structured learning, I highly recommend Linux Academy (https://linuxacademy.com). They have an excellent Introduction to Google Cloud Platform course, and they offer a seven day free trial.

---

There are two ways to create duplicate VM's: Instance groups or Snapshots. Given what you're trying to accomplish, I think snapshots will be your best bet.

Once your VM has all your software installed and configured, you need to take a snapshot of it. You can take snapshots with the VM running, but I think it's cleaner to shut the VM down first.

To create the snapshot, go to https://console.cloud.google.com. Make sure you are in the same project as your original VM. You can check what project you're in by looking to the right of the words "Google Cloud Platform" up in the blue bar at the top of your browser screen. It's a dropdown menu, so if you are not in the correct project you can change to it. Then, to the left of the words "Google Cloud Platform" click the hamburger menu (the three horizontal lines). Scroll up and down until you find "Compute Engine". Hover your mouse cursor over it and another menu should pop out to the right. Click "Snapshots". Assuming you haven't created any other snapshots, there should be a blue "Create snapshot" button in the center of the screen. Click it. You can name it whatever you'd like, just as long as you use only lower case letters, numbers and hyphens. Click on the "Source disk" dropdown, and you should see the name of the VM you already created. Select it. You can leave everything else at the default and click the blue "Create" button. Once the snapshot has been created, a green check will appear to the left of the snapshot name.

Now you can create the rest of your VM's. On the left menu, click "VM instances". You should see the VM you already created. In the menu above the list of VM's, click the "CREATE INSTANCE" button. You're going to build this VM pretty much the same way you built the first, but with one difference. In the section titled "Boot disk", click the "Change" button. A list should pop up with all of the different operating systems that Google Cloud offers. At the top of the list are the options "OS images", "Application images", "Custom images", "Snapshots", and "Existing disks". Click "Snapshots". You should see the snapshot you created. Click it so that it is selected. Feel free to change the size of the disk if necessary, and then click the blue "Select" button. Change any other settings that may be appropriate for your VM, and then click the blue "Create" button. It will be created using your snapshot as a source, so it should be virtually identical to your original VM. Continue creating additional VMs using your snapshot as the source until you have created the amount you require.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. I was able to create a single VM in the cloud engine and install what i needed in it. Now i want to create a cluster of node without using a container. and no i couldn't find how to do this in the cloud.google.com.

Comment: I just revised my answer with details on how to use snapshots to create duplicate VM's. Hope it helps!